# How to pass the radio button value to another web page using a button in ASP.NET Core MVC (C#)?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How to pass the radio button value to another web page using a button in ASP.NET Core MVC (C#) ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a controller as below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Greetings(string name)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = name;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here first action/method Index returns a View/Page & it takes input from the user. which we will show another page.

```
 @{
        Layout = null;
    }
     
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Greetings", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox("Name")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </body>
    </html>
```

When the user clicks on the Submit button. then It loads another page with the user input value.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Greetings</title>
</head>
<body>
     <span>Name: </span>@ViewBag.Name
</body>
</html>
```